# Java: How to show Hello World! after button has been clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, cardlayout

I would like to learn how you go to a next 'frame or screen' in Java.

I'm learning Java and got the Hello World App working,
My next step is to have a button and after its being clicked I want the 
Hello World! to appear.

So first the button and then the Hello World in the next 'frame'
I call it frames but don't know how it's called for Java.
I use windows7 and notepad by the way

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find a swing tutorial that fits you. There are many, such as [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [this](http://www.zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/) (first on google...)

Basically, you need to put a `JButton` in a `JPanel` and then put the `JPanel` in your main `JFrame`. Also, to display the "hello world" screen you need to create ActionListener that displays it and add it to your button.

Answer (score 3):

There are many options, but in this case you might look to use a [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion here, but I found it very useful to use a Java oriented IDE when learning java (JDevelopepr in my case).  You should try it out.  Now to answer your question, you will have to call your button's AddMouseListener method and pass it an object of a class that implements MouseListener.  Refer to the [Oracle website](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) for more info as this would be a rather long post.

Comment: "you will have to call your button's AddMouseListener method"  Rubbish.  Adding an ActionListener makes a lot more sense for a button, since the button can then be activated by either mouse **or** keyboard.